# Javascript giving undefined error although it seems like everything is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
success: function (result) {
                    var messages = result;
                    for(var i=0;i<=messages.length;i++) 
                        jQuery("#responseMessages").jqGrid(
                                                            'addRowData',
                                                            i+1,
                                                            {distance:messages[i].distance,age:messages[i].age,message:messages[i].message}
                                                          );
                }
```

So this is my success callback function of an Ajax call to my mvc app. It then loops through the response and enters each row in a JQgrid. However, I'm getting this error on my page:

```
messages[i] is undefined
```

even though all the rows are there and it seems to work fine...

Comment: @Scott What's the point of having a local variable which is nothing more than an alias for the first argument? If you don't like the argument name, just rename it.

Comment: @Scott Also, I recommend braces `{}` for the for statement.

Comment: @Scott Also, jQuery lookups inside loops are not recommended. Perform the lookup prior to the loop: `var grid = $('#responseMessages');` and then use the `grid` variable inside the loop.

Comment: Sime, I dont think that works in IE =/

Comment: @Scott What do you mean?

Comment: @Scott - Please, for the love of baseball, format your code in a sane way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to remove the `=` in `<=` in your `for` loop.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hFvV/).

Seeing as you are using jQuery, you could also use its [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over that.

Comment: sometimes you just need a second set of eyes huh?

Comment: @Scott Yeah, I thought it was a case of the `<=` when I saw the `messages[i] is undefined` error :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, success arguments are strings. I assume that it is a string in your case too. In that case, you cannot perform index lookups `[i]`...